# How to debug C function in XCode Debugger

Tags: xcode, debugging, llvm

In my iOS code, I have the following code

```
(char *)xmlTextReaderValue(reader)
```

How can I can see what this C function returns in XCode? I know that if it was Objective C object I could use `po` to print the object. Is there any alternative for C functions?

Comment: You drop the `o` from `po` and you're left with the `p` command...

Comment: By the way, this isn't really something about Xcode, it's rather about the `lldb` debugger it uses. (The same instruction works with `gdb`, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

If your `char *` contains printable data (like a well formed string that is `NULL` terminated, you can simply use the `p` command, explicitly casting the result:

```
p (char *) xmlTextReaderValue(reader)
```

Comment: Since there's probably no type information and for C functions lldb can't query the runtime, you have to explicitly cast: `p (char *) xmlTextReaderValue(reader)`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @NikolaiRuhe, added details to my answer.